# Android Animation with fillAfter set to true resets after clicking anywhere

Tags: java, android, user-interface, animation, android-resources

In my Android project, I have a `Button` which is supposed to "animate out" after being clicked (and stay hidden). The effect is implemented as an AnimationSet defined in `anim` resources, which I'm loading using `AnimationUtils`. To freeze the animation on its last frame, I'm using `setFillAfter(true)`.

```
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v != button) return;
    this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), R.anim.out_to_back);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);
            button.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    });
}
```

The animation resource itself is defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false"
    android:fillAfter="true"
    android:duration="400">
    <alpha
        android:fromAlpha="1.0"
        android:toAlpha="0.0" />
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:toYScale="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%" />
</set>
```

After being clicked, the button animates as expected. The problem is, however, that the **animation resets when I click anywhere else**. A simple demo:

[image: Button fade-out animation being reset after clicking anywhere]

Is this a bug, or am I missing something really obvious? Thanks for any ideas!

## Additional information

- it doesn't matter whether I set `fillAfter` in code, in the XML resource, or both
- when setting it in XML, it doesn't matter whether I apply it on the `<set>` element, or on both of the individual "components" `<alpha>` and `<scale>`
- the preview was captured on an emulator running API 16
- this does not happen on API 22

PS: I'm aware I'm better off using `Animator`, not the `Animation` APIs (unless I need to target pre-Honeycomb, which I don't)
I'm probably gonna switch to `Animator` anyway and see if this behavior persists. But I'm curious what's going on here anyway!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can try right away is to set the `android:fillEnabled="true"` attribute in your animation xml along with `fillAfter`. I'm not sure if that will help, but I know that's worked for some scenarios.

If that doesn't work, your other option is to set an `AnimationListener` for your animation, and then set your button's visibility to `GONE` once the animation has completed. This will make it so once the fade out happens, the button will be removed from the View until you choose to bring it back again. It would look something like this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(button.getContext(), R.anim.out_to_back);
animation.setFillAfter(true);
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        button.setVisibility(View.GONE); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
button.startAnimation(animation);
```

It may complain that your `button` variable is not final. You should be able to fix that by simply assigning the View that comes in through your `onClick` method to a local final variable, like `final View buttonView = v;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I forgot to mention that fillEnabled didn't help; I actually read about it not long ago: http://graphics-geek.blogspot.cz/2011/08/mysterious-behavior-of-fillbefore.html

Comment: Also setting Visibility to GONE was my "workaround" solution for a few days now. I could get used to it, but another thing I didn't mention is I'm developing in Xamarin / C#. I only recreated it in Java in a separate Android Studio project to isolate the problem and to paste here in a language more common to Android. And the thing is there are no such "inline interface implementations" in C#; my entire Activity would have to inherit from IAnimationListener, and that particular Activity is a monster already...

Comment: Anyway, your answer does contain some helpful tips, hence the upvote :)